# Pandas HDFStore query returning maximum date

Tags: python, pandas, hdfstore

I have a large data-set (>100M rows) which I have put in to an HDF store for analysis with Pandas. It is too large to fit in to memory in its entirity. I would like to be able to select the row which has a maximum or minimum datetime value in the `setup` field for the data-set.

So, something like the equivalent of

```
df.ix[df['setup'].idxmax()]
```

if the whole data-set were in memory. Any suggestions?